# Cannot enter to community using SSO

Tags: single-sign-on, authentication, login, identity, authorization

I have an IDP provider(from third party) and configured an SSO connection (on my org).
After authorization on IDP, I try to log in to the community by following the link I took in the SSO settings for the community. But I can't do it and I get this message.

[image]

Login history shows

[image]

Analyzing the SAML request, I saw that it redirects me to the central page of the organization and not on the community(users with this profile have restrictions for access to the main org page(only to the community) if i use admin profile i enter to main org page).

If I use a link from SSO for the central page I can enter to central page (for user with admin profiles or Customer Community Plus Login).

My goal to enter to the community using this link https://X.force.com/Community name/login?so=00D1XXXXXXXXX

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a different URL from the Authentication Provider.

1. Go to your auth. provider
2. expand `Experience Cloud Sites`
3. scroll down and find the name of your site/community. There should be a different SSO URL for your community

Comment: I use a special link for this community. I take this link from the SSO setup page. Did you mean that?

Comment: Yes. Because you said you were able to log in to your internal salesforce through the same SSO. So I assume that your configuration is correct and there are different URLs for logging in to external communities.  Sorry for assuming you were using auth provider.

Comment: Thx for the answer but i use the correct URL for a specific community. Any other ideas?